# Is there a way to sort tags with javascript by using the reverse of an insertion sort?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to use an insertion sort in javascript in order to sort tr tags inside a tbody tag. 
Each tr tag is an alert and has multiple td tags with various informations about the alarm like the person who send the alarm, the one that takes care of it, etc... but the one I need for the sorting is the td with the duration of the alert put as a string inside of it (for example: 00h 01m 42s) and it increases each two seconds. 
Each tr tag also has a class between these three: "success", "warning" and "danger". If the class is "success" the duration time is displayed as for example: "Done at: 00h 02m 10s" and it doesn't increase.
I need to sort the tr tags by the duration time from newest to oldest or oldest to newest and put the "success" class tags at the end in order to have "warning" and "danger" class tags (no matter the order for those two) at the top of the tbody tag when I sort my tags by the duration of the alarms.

I have already been able to do the sorting from newest to oldest and I have a function that puts the tags with a "success" class at the end but the sorting from oldest to newest doesn't work and for some reason the "success" class tags are not put at the end when that kind of sorting is chosen.
I tried to do the sorting from oldest to newest by doing the reverse of what I do with the sorting from newest to oldest but it doesn't work.

Here is the sortByTime() function I created in order to sort the tags by the duration, I use document.getElementById("tableBody") in order to get the tbody to which I have given "tableBody" as an id attribute on my page:

```
function sortByTime(order) {
var rows, tableBody, i, j, sortTime, temp;
tableBody = document.getElementById("tableBody");
rows = tableBody.rows;
sortTime=function (temporary, tabIndex, mode) {
    if(mode>0){
        return temporary<tabIndex;
    }else {
        return temporary>tabIndex;
    }

};
switch (order) {
    case "newest":
        for(i=1;i<rows.length;i++){
            temp=rows[i];
            j=i-1;
            while (sortTime(temp.childNodes[4].innerHTML, rows[j].childNodes[4].innerHTML,1)&& j>0){
                rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[j+1], rows[j]);
                j--;
            }
        }
        sortAlerts("put success last");
        break;
    case "oldest":
        for(i=rows.length;i===0;i--){
            temp=rows[i];
            j=i+1;
            while (sortTime(temp.childNodes[4].innerHTML, rows[j].childNodes[4].innerHTML,0)&& j>0){
                if(rows[i].getAttribute("class")!=="success"){
                    rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[j+1], rows[j]);
                }
                j++;
            }
        }
        sortAlerts("put success last older");
        break;
}
}
```

And here is the sortAlerts() function that I created in order to sort the tags by their classes by using a switch. But in order to put the "success" class at the end, I made a case "put success last" in order to differentiate it from the "success" case that puts the "success" class tags on top:

```
 function sortAlerts(sortWord) {
 if(alerts.length>0){
    var rows, rowToMove, tableBody, i;
    tableBody = document.getElementById("tableBody");
    rows = tableBody.rows;
    if(prevSortWord===sortWord){
        return;
    }
    prevSortWord=sortWord;
    if(sortWord==="put success last older"){
        sortWord="put success last";
    }
    switch (sortWord) {
        case "danger":
            for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                rowToMove = rows[i].getAttribute("class");
                if (rowToMove === "danger") {
                    rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i], rows[0]);
                }

            }
            break;
        case "warning":
            for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                rowToMove = rows[i].getAttribute("class");
                if (rowToMove === "warning") {
                    rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i], rows[0]);
                }

            }
            break;
        case "success":
            for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                rowToMove = rows[i].getAttribute("class");
                if (rowToMove === "success") {
                    rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i], rows[0]);
                }

            }
            break;
        case "put success last":
            for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                rowToMove = rows[i].getAttribute("class");
                if (rowToMove === "success") {
                    rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i], rows[rows.length-1]);
                }

            }
            break;
    }
}

}
```

The prevSortWord variable is a variable from outside the function which only serves to prevent that the sorting can't be done by calling the function two times in a row because otherwise the tags would end up being sorted in reverse with the cases that aren't "put success last".

I need a way to do the reverse sorting of the "newest" case in the sortByTime() function for the "oldest" case because all that the "oldest" case does is to sort the tags in a manner I don't really understand because when I try to debug it, each line of the code that is read apparently does the swapping of places inside the tbody tag even if the line that is supposed to do it isn't read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a bit of difficulty reasoning the above functions, but what I suspect to be the case is that:

1. The sortByTime function is not actually checking the time in the table row, and
2. there could be something up with the order that element insertion happens

I wrote a similar function that behaves slightly differently. Hopefully it will be of some use for you:

```
// Returns the sort-comparable timestamp (you'll want to change this)
function getTimeInt (timeStr) {
  return timeStr.substring(timeStr.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1)
}

function sortAlerts (word, _reverse = false) {
  const tableBody = document.querySelector('#tableBody')
  const reverse = _reverse ? -1 : 1

  // Sort the rows, and add them back to the tableBody
  Array.apply(null, tableBody.querySelectorAll('tr'))
    .sort(function(rowA, rowB) {
      // Change this function return to do different things, like putting success at bottom
      return (
        (rowA.classList.contains(word) - rowB.classList.contains(word)) ||
        ((getTimeInt(rowA.innerText) - getTimeInt(rowB.innerText)) * reverse)

      )
    })
    .forEach(function (row) {
      row.parentNode.removeChild(row)
      tableBody.appendChild(row)
    })

}

// Put danger at top, and reverse the search
sortAlerts('danger', true)
```

And here's the jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/r6sxmko7/

I'm sorry I couldn't be more helpful.

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to mention that there are also multiple other td tags inside the tr tags that have text for things like the type of the alarm (if it is an alarm of an old person who fell down for example) or the name of the person who is responsible to take care of the alarm, etc...

Comment: Alright! I was able to adapt the code that you gave me and now it works perfectly! And I was even able to put it all in the sortAlerts() function. Thank you very much! I would have showed you how it looks now but I don't know how to put the code in the coment ^^'